# msbuild and cruiscontrol.net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to call a batch file insdie cruisecontrol and all the batch file does it calls msbuild on a .sln C# project. I can't get this to work and I get the following error :
'msBuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command
Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why call a batch file when you have the MSBuild task?

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/MsBuild+Task

Also - you may want to make sure the batch file works outside of CruiseControl.Net.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to put specify the full path to msbuild:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like "msbuild" isn't in your search path.  Either update the "path" environment variable or specify the full path to the msbuild.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here is an example of one of my msbuild tasks...

```
<tasks>
  <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>D:\INETPUB\wwwroot\CruiseControl\Utilities\</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>Utilities.csproj</projectFile>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
    <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
  </msbuild>
  <artifactcleanup   cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"   cleanUpValue="5" />
</tasks>
```

This should be nested under your project node.
[Brandon Joyce](http://blog.sonerdy.com)